How to run data driven testing with Complex JSON Request Body in Postman?
I am currently testing microservices and creating a request body to run the data driven testing postman, but I ran into a problem that my JSON Request body is bit complex (multiple level of data and arrays) to me to create a generic request body in Postman to accept the test data in run (using collection runner) the data are in a array . I have a created a simple JSON body to run the test. it the sample structure of my JSON request body.
{
    "data1": "{{data1}}",
    "data2": "{{data2}}",
    "data3": "{{data3}}",
    "data4": "{{data4}}",
    "nestedData": {
        "subData1": "{{subData1}}",
        "subDataArray": [
            "{{subDataArrayItem1}}",
            "{{subDataArrayItem2}}",
            "{{subDataArrayItem3}}"
        ],
        "subData2": "{{subData2}}",
        "subData3": "{{subData3}}",
        "nestedArray": [
            {
                "innerData1": "{{innerData1}}",
                "innerData2": "{{innerData2}}",
                "innerNestedArray": [
                    {
                        "deepData": "{{deepData1}}",
                        "deepData2": "{{deepData2}}"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "innerData1": "{{innerData3}}",
                "innerData2": "{{innerData4}}",
                "innerNestedArray": [
                    {
                        "deepData": "{{deepData3}}",
                        "deepData2": "{{deepData4}}"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

The values from Data1 to Data4 is only extracted, showing in request body to  runnable from postman. the values from nested data to deepdata are not able to extract and run the test .
I have tried changing the structure of the request body and altered the JSON body. But the values from nested data to deepdata is unable to extract and put it as an test data in the request body.

Not really sure what you mean here.  You appear to be mixing up the request body and data file of which both are JSON.  The data file JSON needs to be an array of objects.  That is the only format that the collection runner will accept for JSON data files.  You can't use complex JSON in the data file.  Or you could just use a CSV file instead with each of those variable names as column headers.

ok the problem is i can't run nested values  json body  in the collection runner. if there is a work around please tell me
